# Menu item icon color showing in gray not showing its orignal colors

Tags: android, android-layout

I used `navigation drawer` to design the menu of my app for first time, I change the menu icon by my `xml code` but the icon in activity is showing like gray overlay i used `itemIconTint` but it not showing right. My icon have different colors how can i display my icon with all colors[image: Image1 of menu]

My trip icon is showing gray as shown , and after setting `itemIconTint` all goes to orange color [image: Image 2 of menu]

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i understand this scenario.. please include codes so that i can check where you have gone wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below code :

Programmatically

```
yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

From XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black" 
    ... />
```